# lost connection with smtp.strato.de[81.169.145.133] while receiving the initial server greeting

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, linux-networking

49BAC4185F     3057 Sat Mar 24 06:02:32  MAILER-DAEMON
(delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with smtp.strato.eu[81.169.145.133] while receiving the initial server greeting)

3400 mails in queue

i don't get a solution, please anybody guide me to solve the issue

mailbox_size_limit = 51200000

but i have edited the mailbox_size_limit in main.cf as 102100000

Comment: Probably they don't want any more mail from you and just disconnect every time your server tries to connect.

Comment: so this may be by dkim issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were delivering too fast, so your IP was blocked, at least temporarily.  You may want to tune the output of the mail so you don't deliver so fast again.

Look into a few lines for your main.cf

```
default_destination_rate_delay = 5s
default_extra_recipient_limit = 5
```

Comment: thanks for a suggestion, no such a line was inside the main.cf

Comment: They're not in by default, you would need to add them.